SQL Developer query to combine data from multiple columns into single column
I’d like to use something similar to the LISTAGG function but across columns rather than rows. That is to concatenate the values held across multiple columns, that meet certain criteria, into a single column, separated by a semi-colon (;).
Example table data:



ID
DAY1
DAY2
DAY3
DAY4




AAAAAA
Frank
No name
No name
Bob


AAAAAB
Sheila
Frank
No name
Zach



I'd like to return something like this, ignoring all columns that contain 'No name':



ID
LIST




AAAAAA
Frank;Bob


AAAAAB
Sheila;Frank;Zach



I have tried adapting LISTAGG to see if I could get around this but with no joy.
Not sure I can use CONCAT with a condition, i.e. to ignore 'No name', excluding them from the concatenation
The table has a column for each day of the year (365 or 366 columns plus ID) so would rather not use a very long case statement to pull in all values into the single field.

NULLIF(DAY1, 'No name') etc. might do the trick for you when CONCATing yor columns.

LISTAGG() is for aggregating from multiple rows in a group, not aggregating within the same row.

Having a column for each day is an anti-pattern. It's better to have each day in a separate row.

You could unpivot your columns into rows:
select *
from your_table
unpivot (name for day in (day1 as 1, day2 as 2, day3 as 3, day4 as 4))




ID
DAY
NAME




AAAAAA
1
Frank


AAAAAA
2
No name


AAAAAA
3
No name


AAAAAA
4
Bob


AAAAAB
1
Sheila


AAAAAB
2
Frank


AAAAAB
3
No name


AAAAAB
4
Zach



then filter the values and aggregate the remaining values:
select id, listagg(name, ';') within group (order by day)
from (
  select *
  from your_table
  unpivot (name for day in (day1 as 1, day2 as 2, day3 as 3, day4 as 4))
)
where name != 'No name'
group by id;




ID
LISTAGG(NAME,';')WITHINGROUP(ORDERBYDAY)




AAAAAA
Frank;Bob


AAAAAB
Sheila;Frank;Zach



fiddle
You still need to define all 366 days in the in clause, but that's shorter and easier to generate than 366 case expressions.
You might also hit the maximum string length limit, depending on your data distribution; in which case you will probably have to go with the clob/case approach.

Great way to solve this task! Assuming that they need all column names from the table (except for maybe the column id or a few others), maybe you/they could fetch the list of columns from all_tabs_col and then use the result in your query. Something like this: select listagg(column_name, ',') within group (order by column_id) from all_tab_cols where lower(table_name) = 'your_table' and lower(column_name) <> 'id'; Should be simpler than writing them out.

Thanks. My only concern with this approach is that there are just under 8000 unique IDs. Having 365 days as rows per ID then means circa 2.9million records in the unpivoted results. Some great stuff here though.

In a worst case scenario, if there are 10 characters per name and 367 columns that are all populated then, including delimiters, that would give a string 4036 characters long - which will not fit in a VARCHAR2 and will cause LISTAGG to raise an exception.

Yes, hence the last paragraph *8-) Though depends on MAX_STRING_SIZE too of course.

Use a CASE expression to check whether the value is your magic value and, if not, concatenate the delimiter and the value. Then concatenate the values together and strip the leading delimiter.
Like this:
SELECT id,
       SUBSTR(
         EMPTY_CLOB()
         || CASE day1 WHEN 'No name' THEN NULL ELSE ';' || day1 END
         || CASE day2 WHEN 'No name' THEN NULL ELSE ';' || day2 END
         || CASE day3 WHEN 'No name' THEN NULL ELSE ';' || day3 END
         || CASE day4 WHEN 'No name' THEN NULL ELSE ';' || day4 END,
         2
       ) AS list
FROM   table_name;

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (ID, DAY1, DAY2, DAY3, DAY4) AS
SELECT 'AAAAAA', 'Frank', 'No name', 'No name', 'Bob' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'AAAAAB', 'Sheila', 'Frank', 'No name', 'Zach' FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



ID
LIST




AAAAAA
Frank;Bob


AAAAAB
Sheila;Frank;Zach



fiddle

Thank you. By using CASE, and given there are 365/366 Day columns in the table, guessing I’d need to write 365/366 CASE statements?

@MattyC Yes, or copy-paste and edit the numbers. (Or write a program or a spreadsheet formula to generate it for you).

Generate a dynamic sql query
  DO
    $$
    DECLARE
      col_list TEXT;
    BEGIN
      -- Generate the dynamic column list with NULLIF for each column
      SELECT string_agg('NULLIF(' || column_name || ', ''No name'')', ', ')
      INTO col_list
      FROM information_schema.columns
      WHERE table_name = 'your_table' 
        AND column_name LIKE 'DAY%'; -- Assuming your columns are named DAY1, DAY2, etc.
    
      -- Execute the dynamic query
      EXECUTE 'SELECT ID, CONCAT_WS('';'', ' || col_list || ') AS LIST FROM your_table';
    END
    $$;


Hi and thanks - that looks promising although I only have read only access to the DB and not sure if I can execute the above. I will try this and see if I can get it to work. Thanks again.

Oracle tag says which database is being used. Your code isn't Oracle and it won't work.

@Littlefoot The Oracle tag was added after this answer was written.

Thanks, I realised that after adding the Oracle tag. Thanks for spotting and thanks for your input.

You can use a function within a WITH statement in an Oracle SQL.  I would just do it like this.  No special privileges required.   I thought taking care of the 'No name' fields was best handled with a good old fashion replace().
-- Purpose:          The function concat_other_columns concatinates the columns of a table into a single column.
--
-- Parameters:       i_driver_col      -  The field referenced to pull the corelated columns
--                   i_driver_col_name -  The column name of the reference field.
--                   i_table           -  The table name where the reference field is from.
--                   i_recsep          -  Optional column delimeter to be used in the return data.  
--
WITH FUNCTION concat_other_columns(i_driver_col VARCHAR2,i_driver_col_name VARCHAR2, i_table VARCHAR2, i_recsep VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL) RETURN CLOB 
  IS
--  
  CURSOR lc_columns_ref IS
  SELECT column_name,
         data_type,
         column_id on_row,
         (SELECT max(m.column_id) FROM all_tab_columns m WHERE m.table_name = x.table_name) of_rows
    FROM all_tab_columns x
   WHERE table_name = TRIM(UPPER(i_table))
     AND column_name != TRIM(UPPER(i_driver_col_name))
ORDER BY column_id; 
  --
  l_return CLOB;
  l_select VARCHAR2(4000);
  l_delim  VARCHAR2(4000);
  l_query  VARCHAR2(4000);
  --
BEGIN
  --
  IF i_recsep IS NULL THEN
    l_delim := '||'' ''||'; --modify for default delim
  ELSE
    l_delim := '||'''||i_recsep||' ''||';
  END IF;
  --
  FOR l_columns_ref IN lc_columns_ref LOOP
    --
    IF l_columns_ref.data_type = 'DATE' THEN
      l_select := l_select||'to_char('||l_columns_ref.column_name||', ''DD-M ON-YYYY'')';
    ELSE
      l_select := l_select||'to_char('||l_columns_ref.column_name||')';
    END IF;
 --
    IF l_columns_ref.on_row != l_columns_ref.of_rows THEN
      l_select := l_select||l_delim;
    END IF;
    --
  END LOOP;
  --
  l_query := 'SELECT '||l_select||' From  '||trim(upper(i_table))||' WHERE '||i_driver_col_name||' = '''||i_driver_col||''' fetch first 1 rows only';
  --
  EXECUTE  IMMEDIATE l_query INTO l_return;
  --
  RETURN l_return;
  --
END;
--    
SELECT id
     ,  concat_other_columns(id,'ID', 'MY_EXAMPLE', ';') w_recsep
     , replace(concat_other_columns(id,'ID', 'MY_EXAMPLE', ';'), 'No name; ','') w_recsep_and_replace_cleanup
     , concat_other_columns(id,'ID', 'MY_EXAMPLE') wo_recsep_defined
  FROM my_example;




ID
w_recsep
w_recsep_and_replace_cleanup
wo_recsep_defined




AAAAAA
Frank; No name; No name; Bob
Frank; Bob
Frank No name No name Bob


AAAAAB
Sheila; Frank; No name; Zach
Sheila; Frank; Zach
Sheila Frank No name Zach



